# Manage events among users

Tags: 7

I'm creating a community site where users should be able to create events and participate in other users events. I guess there are some options, but which modules do you think would work as candidates for building such a site?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty simple by creating a content type (for example, *Events*), with the date fields implemented by the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module and use the [Signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) module for users to RSVP. For the calendar,  there are at least two modules.

- The [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) module
- The [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module

Both the modules have a Drupal8/9 release.